# After logging in the user is not directed to the homepage

Tags: 8, users

I noticed that when I login I get redirected to `localhost/mysite/user/1` and not `localhost/mysite` or `localhost/mysite/homepage`. Why is this and what can I do about to **make the user go to the homepage after logging in ?**

Comment: `Why is this` this is just simply the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a default option.
But you can redirect user to any page by using [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x)
Example:

```
 /*
* Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
*/

     function YOUR_MODULE_OR_THEME_NAME_form_user_login_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
      // Alter login form and add own custom submit handler.
      array_push($form['#submit'], '_custom_user_login_form_submit');
    }



 /**
 * Custom submit handler for login form.
 */

    function _custom_user_login_form_submit($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $parameter = 'some_value';
        // Set redirect to login form.
      $form_state->setRedirect('custom_page', ['parameter' => $parameter]);
    }
```

For the front page default front page name is view.frontpage.page_1. So it should be

```
 function _custom_user_login_form_submit($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {

          $form_state->setRedirect('view.frontpage.page_1');
        }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly I have to add the code written above in the form.api.php in \core\lib\Drupal\Core\Form ?

Comment: You have to add this code to your theme_name.theme file of to your_module_name.module file and clear cache. Here YOUR_MODULE_OR_THEME_NAME is a name of your theme or module.

Comment: You have to add this code to your theme_name.theme file OR to your_module_name.module file and clear cache. Here YOUR_MODULE_OR_THEME_NAME is a name of your theme or module.